# Load and formatting file in python

Tags: python, split, formatting, load

I have a file with n lines, I would like to load in python, the format is this

```
06:38:34 16.09.2017,  739648.4118,6077976.8575, 54.791616, 12.727939
06:38:35 16.09.2017,  739647.0628,6077975.6925, 54.791606, 12.727917
```

I would like it to be like:

```
06 38 34 16 09 2017 739648.4118 6077976.8575  54.791616  12.727939
06 38 35 16 09 2017 739647.0628 6077975.6925  54.791606  12.727917
```

So it becomes an array with size(n,10).
I have tried

```
f=open('filename')
x.read()
f.close()
```

Then x is a string with size(1) with all the data in the one element. I know there is a command called `split` but I cannot get it to work properly. Can any help?

Comment: `.split()` only works with one type of character, you would need to split on two different types (',' and ':') to get the output you want. What do you want to do with the output? If you want to do any kind of data analysis on it, I would suggest using `pandas` to load and wrangle the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want to achieve using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('<your file>', header=None, names=['DateTime', 'Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3', 'Num4'])
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

# Split datetime object in to seperate columns as desired output format
df['hour'] = df['DateTime'].dt.hour
df['minute'] = df['DateTime'].dt.minute
df['second'] = df['DateTime'].dt.second
df['day'] = df['DateTime'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['DateTime'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['DateTime'].dt.year

# Drop the DateTime columns
df.drop('DateTime', inplace=True, axis=1)

# Switch the order of columns to desired order
df = df[['hour', 'minute', 'second', 'day', 'month', 'year', 'Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3', 'Num4']]

#export to file with ' ' as seperator
df.to_csv('output file.txt', sep=' ', index=False, header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
with open('filename','r') as f:
    out = []
    a = f.read().replace(':',' ').replace(',','').split('\n')
    for i in a:
       out.append(i.split(' '))
    print(out[0:-1])
```

`[0:-1]` to drop the last empty element

Answer (score 0):

I always like to handle file processing using a pipeline approach, that way you can use concurrency if your input gets really big. Anyway, you can easily check the performance using `%timeit` if you are using ipython, but here is what I would do:

```py
processed = ""

def replace_char(line, char, replacement):
    return line.replace(char, replacement)

with open('SOME_PATH') as fh:
    processed += replace_char(replace_char(fh.read(), ":", " "), ",", "")

print(processed)

# OUTPUT
# 06 38 34 16.09.2017  739648.41186077976.8575 54.791616 12.727939
# 06 38 35 16.09.2017  739647.06286077975.6925 54.791606 12.727917
```

With this approach if you want to make changes to the way you process the file all you have to do is change replace_char, or write some other function if you like. If you need concurrency then you can use the `multiprocessing` or `asyncio` packages.